# Binding to UserControl property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have an UserControl property in the presenter:

```
public UserControl Control { get; set; }
```

The XAML code:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Control}"/>
```

When I run the application I get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'Presenters' property not found on 'object' ''MainPresentet'
>   (HashCode=24706823)'. BindingExpression: Path=Presenters;
>   DataItem='MainPresenter' (HashCode=24706823); target element is
>   'ItemsControl' (Name=' '); target property is 'ItemSource' (type
>   'IEnumerable')

I tried to change the property to IEnumerable and use ItemsControl and I got same error.

I dont know the name of the UserControl because I get him from other dll in runtime

Comment: Error is not in the code you have shown. Do you have a `ItemsControl` somewhere? Something is bound to `Presenters` property and its complaining that it cannot found any such property in your `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty clear:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Presenters' property not found on 'object' ''MainPresentet' (HashCode=24706823)'. BindingExpression: Path=Presenters; DataItem='MainPresenter' (HashCode=24706823); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=' '); target property is 'ItemSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

This means that somewhere in your code, you have tried to data bind to a property named `Presenters`, but that the `DataContext` where you tried that is actually set to an object of type `MainPresenter` and this object does *not* have a public `Presenters` property declared in it. This `Binding` was set on an `ItemSource` property of an `ItemsControl`, or derived class, like a `ListBox`.

Therefore, this error has nothing to do with your displayed code and you will need to search your code for the `Presenters` `Binding Path` and fix that `Binding`.